Inequality of Lübke
The following famous inequality by Lübke is given in Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles by S. Kobayashi

Let $(E, h)$ be an Hermitian vector bundle of rank $r$ over a compact Hermitian manifold $(M, g)$ of dimension n with Kähler form $\Phi$. If $(E, h)$ satisfies the weak Einstein condition, then $$\int_M \left((r-1)c_1(E,h)^2-2rc_2(E,h)\right)\wedge \Phi^{n-2} \le 0$$ and the equality holds if and only if $(E,h)$ is projectively flat, i.e. $R^i_{j\alpha\bar{\beta}} = (1/r)\delta^i_jR_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}$.

I have two questions about this. The inequality seems very mysterious, what is the history behind it and how is this supposed to be meaningful in any way? Secondly, how is being projectively flat the same thing as $$R^i_{j\alpha\bar{\beta}} = \frac{1}{r}\delta^i_jR_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}?$$
There is a proposition in the book stating that $E$ being projectively flat implies that $$\text{End}(E) = E^* \otimes E$$ is flat, but I don't know if this is equivalent to the given equality.
